# Blazor Asp.Net Core Identity with custom user database

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-server-side

I'm writing a Blazor server application.
In this I would like to use my own user database and not that of Asp.Net Core Identity.
Does anyone have an example of this?
Or can I write a CustomUserManager?
I simply want a login with username and password that is validated in my own database.

Comment: B2C could help you for this if you are hosting in Azure.

Comment: Is it you simply don't want to use two databases, or you have some more specific needs that the standard stuff doesn't cover.  If it's the first then import the relevant tables into your database and point the identity service to your database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ASP.NET Core Identity is an API that supports user interface (UI) login functionality and helps to manage users, passwords, profile data, roles, claims, tokens, email confirmation, and more. And it is using the EF core to access data from database. If you want to use your own database, you could [change the connection string](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/walkthroughs/existing-database) to yours.

If you don't want to use Asp.net core Identity, you could create the Account or Role controller by yourself, and add the login page. Then refer the [EF core tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/crud?view=aspnetcore-5.0) to connect the database, and then manage users and roles or validate users.